# A função MouseClick do autoit fecha o script

Tags: script

Criei uma `HotKeySet` no autoit, mas quando uso a função MouseClick, está fechando o script. Segue o código a seguir:

```vb
HotKeySet("^9", "clicar")  

func clicar()  
   MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 8, 40, 1, 1)  
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma: criei as variáveis dentro da função:

func clicar()
$x=8
$y=40

MouseClick("left", $x, $y, 1, 1)
EndFunc

Sendo que os dois últimos parâmetros são a quantidade do click (1) e a velocidade que o mouse vai para a coordenadas x e y (0, ou seja, imediatamente).